# how to redirect to a specific screen from search results in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api

I've done all my API integration parts and results are also displaying in my App. For Ex. I've a `ShowPackageDetails` API, which giving me the specific package details on a page after clicking the `Show Details` button

Now I also implemented a global search where users search and if this came in search results I want to redirect to the same `Details` page.These search results are dynamic so how can I specifically redirect to the `details` page for each item after search?

Here after searching for `Angi_ _ _` I want to redirect to the same `Angioplasty details` page after clicking the "**Show Details**" button in search results for this specific item.

Example 1`API` integration

```
class SurgPackDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  final String encId;
  SurgPackDetails({this.encId='IujvK/FS7g=='});
  @override
  _SurgPackDetailsState createState() => _SurgPackDetailsState();
}

class _SurgPackDetailsState extends State<SurgPackDetails> {

  static String url="http://myapikkkk";
  Dio dio = Dio();

  SurgicalData _surgicalData=SurgicalData(packageId: '', encPackageId: '',
      packageName: '', note: '', createBy: '', createDate: '',
      modBy: '', modDate: '', activeStatus: '', permission: '',
      fee: '', discountedFee: '', bookingFee: '',
      description: '');

  late List<PartnerDatum> surgPartnerData = [];
  late List<PartnerDatum> _finalsurgpartnerData = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDocDetails(widget.encId);
  }
  Future getDocDetails(id) async{
    dynamic data={"EncId": id};
    print(id);
    Response res = await dio.post(url, data: data);

    print(res.data);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print('loop starts');

      SurgicalData surgdata=SurgicalData(
          packageId: res.data['SurgicalData']['PackageId'],
          encPackageId: res.data['SurgicalData']['EncPackageId'],
          packageName: res.data['SurgicalData']['PackageName'],
          note: res.data['SurgicalData']['Note'],
          createBy: res.data['SurgicalData']['CreateBy'],
          createDate: res.data['SurgicalData']['CreateDate'],
          modBy: res.data['SurgicalData']['ModBy'],
          modDate: res.data['SurgicalData']['ModDate'],
          activeStatus: res.data['SurgicalData']['ActiveStatus'],
          permission: res.data['SurgicalData']['Permission'],
          fee: res.data['SurgicalData']['Fee'],
          discountedFee: res.data['SurgicalData']['DiscountedFee'],
          bookingFee: res.data['SurgicalData']['BookingFee'],
          description:res.data['SurgicalData']['Description'],
      );

      var k = res.data['PartnerData'].length;

      print('Loop for partner data');
      PartnerDatum obj;
      for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        obj =PartnerDatum(
            partnerId: res.data['PartnerData'][i]['PartnerId'],
            encPartnerId: res.data['PartnerData'][i]['EncPartnerId'],
            partnerName: res.data['PartnerData'][i]['PartnerName'],
            partnerAddress: res.data['PartnerData'][i]['PartnerAddress'],
            fee:res.data['PartnerData'][i]['Fee'],
            discountedFee: res.data['PartnerData'][i]['DiscountedFee'],
            bookingFee: res.data['PartnerData'][i]['BookingFee'],
            dayList: res.data['PartnerData'][i]['DayList'],
        );
        surgPartnerData.add(obj);

        }
      setState(() {
        _surgicalData=surgdata;
        _finalsurgpartnerData=surgPartnerData;
        // _docData=doctorData;
        // _partnerData=;
      });
    } else {
      print(res.statusCode);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${_surgicalData.packageName} details', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed'),),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: [
                Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .primaryColor,
                Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .accentColor
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(

        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
            child: Column(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [

                Container(
                  // height: 250,
                  // width: 200,
                  // color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [

                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0,horizontal: 10),
                        child: Text(_surgicalData.packageName,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25,color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',),),
                      ),

                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.topRight,
                            colors: [
                              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              Theme.of(context).accentColor
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                                child: Text('Description:',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 22,color:Colors.white,fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',),),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                child: Text(_surgicalData.description,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17,color:Colors.white,fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',),),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  // height: 500,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // color: Colors.green,
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                  ),
                  child:
                  Container(
                    height: 250,
                    // color: Colors.blue,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: surgPartnerData.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                // color: Colors.green,
                                height: 200,
                                width: 300,
                                // margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  // color: Colors.green,
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.center,
                                    colors: [
                                      Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      Theme.of(context).accentColor
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                      child: Text(surgPartnerData[index].partnerName,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',),),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                      child: Text(surgPartnerData[index].partnerAddress,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',),),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height:10),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Actual Fee: ${surgPartnerData[index].fee}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Discount Fee: ${surgPartnerData[index].discountedFee}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Booking Fee: ${surgPartnerData[index].bookingFee}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                    Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      height: 40,
                                      width: 280,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          color: Colors.white
                                      ),
                                      child: Text('BOOK',style: TextStyle(color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor ),),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),

                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      const Divider(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        // height: 5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),


        ],
      ),


    );
  }
}
```

Calling and printing the API result

```
onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => SurgPackDetails(
                                        encId:
                                            surglist[index].encPackageId)));
```

**My `Search` API**

```
    Future<void> searchByUser() async {
    var jsonResponse;
    if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse("http://medjkkjkjkj"),
          body: ({
            'SearchKey': searchController.text,
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
        });
        print("Correct");
        print(response.body);
        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        print(jsonResponse);
         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AfterSearchPage(rresponse: SearchApiResponse.fromJson(jsonResponse))));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(" ${jsonResponse['Message']}"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF152A38),
        ));
         CREDENTIALS
      } else {
        print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
        print(response.body);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid credentials")));
      }
    } else {

    }
  }
```

Then displaying my search results

```
 class AfterSearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final SearchApiResponse rresponse;
  const AfterSearchPage({required this.rresponse});
  @override
  _AfterSearchPageState createState() => _AfterSearchPageState();
}

class _AfterSearchPageState extends State<AfterSearchPage> {
  // var responseRef;
  //  _SecondState(this.responseRef);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.topCenter,
              colors: [
                Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                Theme.of(context).accentColor
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Search Result',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (final item in widget.rresponse.data)
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(item.name),
                        trailing: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text("Show details")),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
                          radius: 30,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(item.image),
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                      Text(item.extra1),
                      Text(item.extra2),
                     
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),

              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html

Comment: No, actually that's for this specific item no? My search results are dynamic . I want them to redirect to their specific details page

Comment: Create a general details page and push that screen while you give the informations as an argument. (`DetailsPage(data: data);`)

Comment: You mean, for each APIs details page `[A to Z checkup,  Angioplasty, Dietician ..etc]`, I should create a general details page? The problem I'm facing three are multiple APIs how can I map them specifically to their details page

Comment: No. You create a page that contains a `Text()` where you type all the informations. Does not matter from where you get the informations, create an object that you give to this page and use the data inside the class. All pages will have a title and description for example. You don't need new pages for all of this. You need one that accepts 2 strings.